# Getting one ID from an table with condition and dastaset from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

My problem is a statement, which gives me a syntax error (I'm working with MS Access).

So here is the issue:

First table (Server) looks like this (there are more columns in it)

| customerID | rack |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 |

Second table (Customer) looks like this

| customerID | fullname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| etc. |  |

In the first table is serverID (not shown here) the PK and customerID is related to it. In the second table is customerID the PK.

Now, I want the name of all costumers in Rack 3 for example.

I tried it this way:

```sql
SELECT customer.fullname, Server.serverID
FROM customer INNER JOIN Server ON customer.customerID = (SELECT customerID FROM Server WHERE Server.rack = 3);
```

Can someone help me?

And maybe someone has a better title for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how much time you spent on this but this is basic join SQL

Try:

```
SELECT customer.fullname, Server.serverID FROM customer 
INNER JOIN Server 
ON customer.customerID = Server.customerID
Where Server.rack = 3
```

Comment: Not much to be honest, but this helped me a lot, thanks! It is also my first database and my first join statement